# Removing python print whitespace

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing, formatting

I am trying to create a python print statement that calls a function within it and returns the value right to the print statement, but because python adds whitespace every time you have a comma, the formatting looks really weird. Is there any way to force python to not add the whitespace that it does in print statements?

```
print("After", yr, "year(s) your balance will be $", compute_compound_interest(ibal, ir, yr),'.')
```

This is what it prints out:

After 1 year(s) your balance will be $ 110.0 .

And I want it to look like:

After 1 year(s) your balance will be $110.00.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try In-line formatting

```
print(f"After {yr} year(s) your balance will be ${compute_compound_interest(ibal, ir, yr)}.")
```

Documentation: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/

Answer (score 0):

Yes:

```
print('A','B','C',sep='')
```

Output:

```
ABC
```

Note that you would need to add spaces where they are desired for example:

```
x = 1
print('After',x,'year',sep='') #prints After1year
print('After ',x,' year',sep='') #prints After 1 year
```

Answer (score 0):

What Daweo said is completely correct, but you could also take a look at python format strings which would make your code look like this:

```py
print("After {} year(s) your balance will be ${}.".format(yr, compute_compound_interest(ibal, ir, yr)))
```